# Wrong position of div and and cannot apply a top margin to a h3 wrapped in the div

Tags: html, css

I have a div `umiejetnosc` contains 2 child divs: `web-development` and `inne`. Both of them have 2 divs that split them. I'm still problem with the position of the `h3` in the child divs.

I'm trying to add a margin to the `h3` headings, and the first one works but the second one doesn't. I have made a screenshot with google dev tools showing that the margin is applied, but position of h3 is wrong. Is that problem with `display: block`?

[image][image]

**HTML**

```
        <div id="umiejetnosci">
        <h2 class="tabStart">Umiejętności</h2>

        <div id="web-development">
        <h3>Technologie Webowe</h3>
            <div class = "nazwaUmiejetnosci">Html</div>
            <div class = "gwiazdkiUmiejetnosci"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"></div>
            <div class = "nazwaUmiejetnosci">SS, SASS</div>
            <div class = "gwiazdkiUmiejetnosci"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"></div>
            <div class = "nazwaUmiejetnosci">Bootstrap</div>
            <div class = "gwiazdkiUmiejetnosci"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"></div>
            <div class = "nazwaUmiejetnosci">Javascript</div>
            <div class = "gwiazdkiUmiejetnosci"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"></div>
            <div class = "nazwaUmiejetnosci">Jquery</div>
            <div class = "gwiazdkiUmiejetnosci"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"></div>
            <div class = "nazwaUmiejetnosci">RWD</div>
            <div class = "gwiazdkiUmiejetnosci"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="inne">
            <h3>Inne</h3>
            <div class = "nazwaUmiejetnosci">C#</div>
            <div class = "gwiazdkiUmiejetnosci"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"></div>
            <div class = "nazwaUmiejetnosci">Photshop</div>
            <div class = "gwiazdkiUmiejetnosci"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"></div>
            <div class = "nazwaUmiejetnosci">Unity 3D</div>
            <div class = "gwiazdkiUmiejetnosci"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"></div>
            <div class = "nazwaUmiejetnosci">C++</div>
            <div class = "gwiazdkiUmiejetnosci"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/skill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"><img src="image/noSkill.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#umiejetnosci{
width: 100%;
background: #ffffff;
overflow: auto;
}

#umiejetnosci h3{
margin: 25px 0 25px 25px;
}

#umiejetnosci img{
width: 30px;
}

#umiejetnosci #web-development{
width: 100%;
}

#umiejetnosci #inne{
width: 100%;
}


.nazwaUmiejetnosci{
width: 25%;
text-align: right;
font-size: 1.2em;
padding: 10px 5% 0 0;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
}

.gwiazdkiUmiejetnosci{
width: 70%;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are floating the `.nazwaUmiejetnosci` and `.gwiazdkiUmiejetnosci` elements so this takes them out of the flow.

You need to use **clearfix** on the parent container, so that any elements underneath clear the floated elements and take up their expected position underneath in their own "space".

```
#web-development:after, #inne:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Alternatively, you can define a `clearfix` class in your CSS, and then you can apply it to any container that has floating elements, e.g. `<div id="web-development" class="clearfix">`

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

And believe me - if you are using floats, you will need this a *lot*!

**Reference** for more info: [CSS Tricks - The Clearfix: Force an Element To Self-Clear its Children](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try, to begin with:

```
div{clear:both;}
```

(it's a better solution than Momo's one with `style` - don't use `style`, at the best).

And to apply it just in the container you want:

```
 section#myContainer div { clear: both; }
```

And erase the spaces in `class = "css"` -> `class="css"`. You can use them, but spaces are devils in programs.

Comment: Yes, you are right that a CSS solution is better than adding HTML elements... however this applies to *every* div in the whole site - which is definitely not a result anyone would want :) EDIT: Also, there's no problem with having spaces around the `=` in `class = "css"`... its a stylistic choice and some people think its easier to read.

Comment: @FluffyKitten. To not apply to every div, it's easy to wrap into a container : `section#my_container div {clear: both;}`. No problem with having spaces until you reg-search for your classes or your tag attributes. Spaces are program's devils. ;-) I agree, thought ;)

Comment: Yes I know that, but you need to include it in your answer for users who don't - many users of Stack Overflow are inexperienced and just learning, so we can't assume they have the knowledge or experience to know this.

Comment: No problem! You should edit your answer to include the info your comment - it's quiet helpful but it won't be noticed in the comments :)

Comment: Done! ;-) Thanks @FluffyKitten

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using float left, just clear the float before id="inne", example

```
...your code
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="inne">
...your code
```

Comment: huh solution was so simple, funny thing i tried with clear, but dont have idea how i messed this up, thx, solved

Comment: @kozi See either of the other answers for a better solution - a CSS solution is *much* preferable to adding HTML elements everywhere you want to clear a float.